# Converting neural net probablities into predictions in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, prediction

Excuse me for my ignorance, as I am learning the theory behind models and in this case neural nets. I trying to train a model using the `library(nnet) library(NeuralNetTools)` packages.

For example, if my code was:

```
#training model on training dataset
nnet_model <- nnet(Morphology~. ,size=10,data=morph_scaled_train, maxit=1500)
#generating predictions
nnet_prediction_prob <- predict(nnet_model,morph_test)
```

This gives the prediction output as numbers. I.e.

```
         Blue           Red           Green       Yellow
1   1.020685e-180  1.000000e+00 4.496185e-255 4.079526e-254
2   1.020685e-180  1.000000e+00 4.496185e-255 4.079526e-254
3   1.020685e-180  1.000000e+00 4.496185e-255 4.079526e-254
```

How could I convert this to a factor i.e. Row 1 is Red, row 2 is blue for example ... Giving the overall prediction. When I use predict function for other models e.g. random forest, logistic regression, it gives it as the overall prediction and not numbers, and this is what I wish for nnets. Is this possible? Or just the way the model works this cannot be interpreted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max.col`:

```
colnames(nnet_prediction_prob)[max.col(nnet_prediction_prob)]
[1] "Red" "Red" "Red"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `type = "class"` within `predict` function to have the class names. You have not provided any data, so I am using `iris` data like

```
library(nnet) 
library(NeuralNetTools)

#training model on training dataset
nnet_model <- nnet(Species~. ,size=10,data=iris, maxit=1500)
#generating predictions
nnet_prediction <- predict(nnet_model, iris, type = "class")
```